# GoogleMaps API with VueJS and Laravel integration

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to integrate a map via GoogleMaps API in my Laravel app. Therefore I chose a setup like this:

**HTML**

```
(...)
<body>

    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div id="app">    
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&libraries=places,geometry&callback=app.init" async defer></script>

</body>
(...)
```

**Javascript VUE**

```
window.Vue = Vue;
window.Event = new class {
    constructor() {
        this.Vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
        this.Vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.Vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
};

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        GISView: GISView
    },
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        init: function() {
            this.$broadcast('MapsApiLoaded');
        }
    }
});
```

When loading the page I find in the dev tools console the message:
[image]

Why is the function app.init not found, as I have set it up in my VUE instance?

Comment: It appears that you also [posted on laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/component-import?page=1) but didn't find a solution there yet. Is [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/import-of-component-not-working/10839) also your post on the VueJS forums?